# Neo4j. Dijkstra. Find paths including a set of nodes (graphalgo)

Tags: java, neo4j, dijkstra

Now I'm testing dijkstra (org.neo4j.graphalgo.impl.shortestpath.*). The code you can see below:

```
 Dijkstra<Double> dijkstra = new Dijkstra<>(0.0,
         startNode,
         endNode,             
         CommonEvaluators.doubleCostEvaluator("weight"),
         new DoubleAdder(),
         new DoubleComparator(),
         Direction.BOTH,
         RelationshipTypes.rel);
```

How I can define nodes which must be included in path? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to brute force all possible paths. As long you dont have to many nodes you want to include you can use this approach. It is basically the traveling sales man problem.
what you can do:

- Find all permutations of nodes (so you order the nodes in all possible ways)
- Start a shortest path for every permutations going from the first to the second node and so on
- Compare the weigth of all paths and take the shortest one

Keep in mind to keep the amount of nodes as small as possible because the TSP is an NP-hard problem. So dont go to close to like 10 nodes to include.

I already requested this feature on github also with some code. 
[Here is my request.](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/733)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've found more simple way to solve it. If my way won't work I'll try yours.

Comment: I'd like to see your solution as well. So pls share yours if it works.

Comment: Yeah, wait 5 minutes. I'll post it as answer to my question. I'm not sure that it's a correct solution but it works.

Comment: added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Yoshi said, this is a TSP. In your solution, you might run into trouble when going through all possible paths as the amount increases quickly on big graphs.

My idea to possibly improve performance would be to run a Dijkstra between each of the nodes you want to have included in your final path and then create a new graph, just with those nodes and the newly calculated distances as weights in it and run the Dijkstra algorithm and the analyzis of wether all nodes are included in a given path on this (considerably) smaller graph.

Comment: My graph consists of 55k nodes and 120K relationships and i find paths in 2 seconds. If build .jar and use it as plugin it will work in ms. Dijkstra is a fast.

Comment: And I like your idea. I'll think about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the simple solution. Just made any changes. Not sure that it's correct but it works.

```
      Dijkstra<Double> dijkstra = new Dijkstra<>(0.0,
                startPoint,
                endPoint,
                new CostEvaluator<Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Double getCost(final Relationship relationship, Direction direction) {

                        if (listIncAll.contains(relationship.getStartNode()) || listIncAll.contains(relationship.getEndNode())) {
                            return 0.0;
                        }else {
                            return relationship.getProperty("weight");
                        }
                    }
                },
                new DoubleAdder(),
                new DoubleComparator(),
                Direction.BOTH,
                RelationshipTypes.rel);


       Map<List<PropertyContainer>, Double> pathMap = new HashMap<>();


        for (List<PropertyContainer> path : dijkstra.getPaths()) {

            if (path.containsAll(listIncAll)) {
                double fullWeight = 0;
                Iterator<PropertyContainer> i = path.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()){
                    i.next();
                    if (i.hasNext()) {
                        Relationship r = (Relationship) i.next();                         
                        fullWeight += r.getProperty("weight");
                    }
                }
                pathMap.put(path,fullWeight);
            }
        }
       System.out.println(pathMap.entrySet().stream().sorted((k1, k2) -> -k2.getValue().                           
    compareTo(k1.getValue())).findFirst().get().getKey());
```

So using CostEvaluator I've found paths which have at least one point from a list of points which must be included. To get paths which have all points I've just added "if (path.containsAll(listIncAll))".  In last sout you'll see the found path.